# Java 8 filter duplicate objects in a list

Tags: java, java-stream

I've a ArrayList:

```
List<EmpData> data;

class Emp {

    Integer id;
    String department;
    String action;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I'm getting data like:

```
1, Food, Add
1, Food, Remove
2, Food, Add
2, Auto, Remove
3, Electric, Add
3, Electric, Remove
3, Food, Remove
```

I want to remove all the records where id & department are same.

That is For EmpId `1` there & department `food`, there are 2 records so remove them.

This way the resultent list will only contain:

```
2, Food, Add
2, Auto, Remove
3, Food, Remove
```

How can filter this list in java 8?

Comment: To be clear - do you want to eliminate corresponding "Add / Remove pairs"?

Comment: @TomHANAX, yes but I want to remove if id & department are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, build a map of how many times an Id/Department combo exists.

Then remove all the entries where the count is greater than 1.

*Example*

```java
List<EmpData> data = List.of();

TreeMap<EmpData, Long> counts = data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(),
        () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(EmpData::getId)
                                  .thenComparing(EmpData::getDepartment)),
        Collectors.counting()));
data.removeIf(e -> counts.get(e) > 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can sort it and then remove all the subsequent:

```java
var sorted = list.stream().sort(Comparator.comparing(EmpData::getId).thenComparing(EmpData::getDepartment)).collect(Collectors.toList());

for(int i = 0; i < sorted.size() - 1; i++){
   var next = sorted.at( i + 1 );
   var current = sorted.at( i );
   if(current.getId().equals(next.getId()) && current.getDepartment().equals(next.getDepartment())){
      sorted.remove(i);
      i--; // check for next element
   }
}
```

Comment: A note - this will not work when multiple records will be there, for example 3 times "3, Electric, Add" and 2 times "3, Electric, Remove". But don't know if this could be the case. Also could be easily fixed.

Comment: @TomHANAX why? i don't see why `action` should cause problem... at the end the OP whats to remove the duplicates of id-departement... actions should be irrelevant no?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia. Thanks, I'll try this. Just to be highlight its `stream().sorted()`, right?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia OK I did not write good example there, but imagine that items are not "in pairs", to be extreme for example 1 add and 10 removes. This algo as I understand it do not search for "real" pairs, so you will end up with one remove, but in fact that was 10 times removed ;) I do not say it is a problem, but it could be. I understood this that we are looking for corresponding pairs grouped by id & department. But maybe I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
       data.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: this won't work if the equals method is not as OP needs... and the best fix is top use `distinctByKey` which will require a new second class as return type